# Batch file /r:4

Tags: batch-file

I am looking at a batch file from somebody else, and found the following line

```
start \program\src\x64\release\program.exe \program\StudyAreas\program100\Calibrate.pjt /r:4
```

While I know this is to run a project, I don't understand what is the use of "/r:4" at the end of line?

Comment: simply voting down is arrogant and irresponsible. I understand this is a silly question. But if you don't know cmd commands too much, this is hard to find an answer by google. I've tried "cmd r", "slash followed by r", or simply copy "/r". Most of the answers are simply for R language.

Comment: It is indeed very infuriating

Comment: Downvoting means that the question "does not show any research effort, is unclear, or is not useful." Your question does not mention what attempts you made to solve the problem yourself, therefore it shows no research effort. You also obfuscated the name of the program so it is unclear where to start looking for an answer. I didn't downvote this, but I understand why somebody would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `/r:4` argument is intended for the `program.exe` application, not the `start` command itself.

Your best bet would be to open a command prompt (`cmd`), and type

```
\program\src\x64\release\program.exe /?
```

This should hopefully give you a list of arguments. Alternatively, you can check the program's code if you have it (which it looks like you do).

Comment: Thank you. This definitely points out the correct direction. I'll try to find it out in the code.